# how install emacs 26 (or whatever latest ver) on mac

Tags: osx, install, emacs26

Someone (in another SE answer) mentioned a feature thats only available in 26,
so I guess now I gotta upgrade.

How do you install emacs 26 on macOS Sierra?

What I tried:

Googled `how install emacs 26 Mac`, 
`brew install emacs`.

Comment: If you like brew, then use brew.  If you like the ease of downloading a self-contained bare-bones pre-packaged app, then have a look at the *Other Versions* link on https://emacsformacosx.com/  If you like building your own, then do that -- you just need `git`, recent versions of `autoconf` and `automake` and the command line developer tools on OSX.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at brew emacs recipe options with `brew info emacs`. It has this option:

```
--devel
    Install development version 26.0.90
```

To replace your current emacs, run:

```
brew unlink emacs
brew uninstall emacs
brew install emacs --devel --with-modules --with-cocoa --with-gnutls \
    --with-librsvg --with-mailutils --with-imagemagick@6
brew linkapps
```

The imagemagick@6 library and emacs devel change frequently so exclude them from automatic updates and do updates manually at convenient times:

```
brew pin imagemagick@6 emacs
```

Comment: I am having following output: `Error: invalid option: --devel`

Answer (score 10):

A current (at time of this comment) way to install the GUI version of Emacs (26.2 at this time) on macOS Mojave is with

```
brew cask install emacs
```

This will install Emacs.app package in to `/Applications` and setup links.  You can launch Emacs via Spotlight or from terminal as expected.

Comment: Just for people who come across this, it's now `brew install --cask emacs --no-quarantine`, with the `no-quarantine` being because of issues with MacOS security.

Comment: Can I do this and tell it to get a specific unreleased version? I have 28.2 but I want to try out version 29.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately `brew linkapps` is now deprecated.

<s>You can use `brew cask install emacs` but it doesn't allow you to download emacs 26 as of 4/1/2018.</s>
EDIT: As [Guilherme Salomé](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9515/guilherme-salom%c3%a9) pointed out, now `brew cask install emacs` will install version `26.1`.

You can though download the build you want from https://emacsformacosx.com/builds.

Comment: `brew cask install emacs` is working now, it is currently downloading the 26.1 version

Comment: It installs version 27.1

Answer (score 6):

This only installs the terminal version of Emacs 26.1. If you (like me) prefer to use the GUI version of Emacs then you can't install it with

```sh
brew install emacs
```

This is because the people who maintain brew have found it cumbersome to maintain and test all the versions and custom options of multiple formulas. [They have since then dropped support for custom options and encourage users to maintain their own taps](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510). As others have mentioned you can use the emacs-mac version or you can also use the emacs-plus version but if you prefer to use the unedited version and with custom flags to support color-fonts, ImageMagick support and all, I suggest you use the version using the following tap [homebrew-emacs-head](https://github.com/daviderestivo/homebrew-emacs-head).

```sh
brew tap daviderestivo/emacs-head
brew install emacs-head --with-cocoa
```

- if you prefer the emacs-head version (presently 27.x)

```sh
brew tap daviderestivo/emacs-head
brew install emacs-head --HEAD --with-cocoa
```

---

- If you prefer the emacs-head version (26.3)

```
brew tap daviderestivo/emacs-head
brew install emacs-head --with-cocoa
brew install emacs-head@26
ln -s /usr/local/opt/emacs-head@26/Emacs.app /Applications
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/emacs-head@26/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs \
           /usr/local/bin/emacs  # This might be useful if you define `emacs` as your editor in .gitconfig file
alias emacs="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"
```

Answer (score 5):

MacOs has its own Emacs. In 2019 it's still 22.x. To use the last Emacs version do

1. In Terminal run `brew cask install emacs` - it will install the latest emacs version to `/Applications` folder.
2. Then edit (or create if you still don't have) your `~/.bash_profile` file adding a new line

   `alias emacs='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw'`.
3. Then run in Terminal `source ./bash_profile` to update bash environment.
4. Then run in Terminal `emacs -version` to ensure that you use the latest Emacs version.

This will let you use Emacs terminal version. If you want to use Emacs UI, just remove `-nw` in the step `2`.

Comment: Installed the GUI version via the web page emacsformacosx.com and was looking for a way to avoid re-installing via `brew`. The alias did the trick (accessing the installation from Apps folder). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Today on Big Sur `brew install emacs` wasn't working for me.

`brew install homebrew/cask/emacs` did the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with Emacs version 26 install it from the source:

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig"

TAG="26"
git clone --depth 1 --branch emacs-${TAG} git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git
cd emacs
make clean
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-compress-install --with-json --with-dbus --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick --with-mailutils
```